# UIWebView Recalculating the intrinsic content size when orientation changes

Tags: ios8, uiwebview, autolayout, screen-orientation

UIWebview is working perfectly whenever its launched first in potrait mode.

But after switching to Landscape mode, even though I specify

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
      [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];


      [self layoutsubviews];
}
```

please advise how can I make the UIWebView to recalculate its intrinsic contentsize as of now its not rendered properly in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

Just have to use the animateAlongsideTransition:completion: method

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{   
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        // do whatever
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    { 

    }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```